# Passing a parameter to the name of the transformation - Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have job where I have two transformation.
My first transformation. I copy rows to result:
[image]

And second transformation where I want to Get rows from result and passing as parameter to Transformation executor:

[image]

In transformation executor I want to have:

[image]

but I get:

```
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : Unable to load the transformation executor because of an error :
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - Unable to load transformation [${SHORT_FILENAME}]
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - 
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - The transformation path D:/GIT/pentaho/TestCase/${SHORT_FILENAME}.ktr is invalid, and will not run successfully.
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - 
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 - 
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.StepWithMappingMeta.loadMappingMeta(StepWithMappingMeta.java:177)
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.transexecutor.TransExecutor.loadExecutorTransMeta(TransExecutor.java:510)
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.transexecutor.TransExecutor.init(TransExecutor.java:470)
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:69)
2021/05/19 14:17:55 - Transformation executor.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the parameter can't change in the transformation, when you use copy rows to result in the transformation in that way, you are implying that the parameter is going to change for each row. Besides, using it in a transformation, all the rows you receive are going to be processed at the same time, or at least in batchs of n rows, so you would be calling n transformations at the same time, I don't know if that's what you are trying to do.

In this case I think you should use a job to call the transformation, maybe you'll need some workaround to pass the parameter value to the transformation to execute (something like using the transformation you are calling, but without the Get results step) so you can use the parameter in the name of the transformation to call because in a job you couldn't do it.